# What's wrong with this purescript constructor?

Tags: purescript

Trying to create a constructor for roman digits:

```
data RomanDigit a = M | D | C | L | V | I

newRomanDigit :: Int -> RomanDigit 
newRomanDigit 1000 = M 
newRomanDigit 500 = D
```

gets error message:

```
in module UserMod
at src\UserMod.purs line 81, column 1 - line 81, column 35


  Could not match kind

    Type

  with kind

    Type -> Type


while checking the kind of Int -> RomanDigit
in value declaration newRomanDigit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gave `RomanDigit` a type parameter `a`, but haven't specified a value for it in the declaration of `newRomanDigit`.

The way you declared it, `RomanDigit` is not a `Type`. `RomanDigit Int` is a `Type`, or `RomanDigit String` is a `Type`, or perhaps `RomanDigit (Array Boolean)` is a `Type`, but `RomanDigit` by itself is a not a `Type`, because it's missing the declared type parameter `a`. This is what the compiler is telling you.

You need to either remove the parameter, e.g.:

```
data RomanDigit = M | D | C | L | V | I
```

Or specify it when using `RomanDigit`, e.g.:

```
newRomanDigit :: Int -> RomanDigit Int
```

Since the parameter is not present in any of the values, I suspect that you didn't really mean to have it there.